# Errors of face mask detection project when running after converting from py to exe

Tags: python, keras, pyinstaller

I'm working on a project that can use webcam to detect people's face and whether they wear mask or not, and I used a model from Kaggle.com (https://www.kaggle.com/nageshsingh/mask-and-social-distancing-detection-using-vgg19). Then, the images will be assigned to two directories ("mask_on","mask_off"). However, when I converted the Webcam.py to Webcam.exe by pyinstaller and tried to run it, errors happened like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "keras\saving\save.py", line 205, in load_model
  File "keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 108, in load
  File "tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 118, in parse_saved_model
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: masknet.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
[11056] Failed to execute script 'webcam' due to unhandled exception!
```

And here is my command

```
pyinstaller webcam.py
```

The directory has several .py files I am using for other purposes.

Later, I tried another command

```
pyinstaller --onefile webcam.py
```

Although the exe file was generated, when I ran it on the cmd

```
C:\Users\Samuel Lee\Desktop\MyPython\Face Mask Detection\dist> Webcam.exe
```

it had the result like the below:

```
[4088] Failed to extract _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd: decompression resulted in return code -1!
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you update the question with the command you used for converting the exe using `pyinstaller` ? Does the directory have more than one `.py` files and if so did you use the `--onefile` extension to take into consideration the same?

Comment: here is some code to train and save a face mask detection model https://www.kaggle.com/reeganviljoen/face-mask-detection/edit

Comment: and here is a program that imports the model and runs it https://github.com/ReeganCodemaster/Covid-19-face-mask-detector

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could not open the link for the Kaggle notebook.